# Is it possible to get the MutationObserver instance for an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, mutation-observers

I'm trying to see if I can find the MutationObserver instance that is observing a HTML element?

My ultimate aim is to `disconnect` all the observers listening to the element.

Comment: No, there's no such API. You can delete the element from DOM and re-add it back at the same position, though.

Comment: Will that detach the observer/s from that element? @wOxxOm

Comment: That's the idea. You need to verify it.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thx.

Comment: FYI Observers are preserved during disconnect/reconnect. This even extends to parts of the subtree (if subtree=true). (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe#observation_follows_nodes_when_disconnected)

Comment: And for verification that this extends to the Observed Element itself: https://codepen.io/modellking/pen/zYWrogv